# I want to find all the greater than 100 MB and older than 20 day and want to zip them only .TXT and .txt files individually

Tags: linux, find, zip

I'm using

```
find $HOME  -type f -size +100M -mtime +20 -exec zip -m '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

This command is compressing all the files. I want to zip only *.TXT and *.txt files only. Any idea how can we do that?

Comment: Instead of an empty `-name` parameter (in fact, shouldn't this generate a syntax error?), use `-iname '*.txt'`. Strictly speaking, this also compresses *.tXT, *.tXt etc, but my hope is that you are fine with that.

Comment: @berndbausch i need ti find all file .TXT,.txt..zip and zip only .TXT & .txt files.

Comment: What do you want to do with the files that are named *.zip? List them? The easiest solution is probably to run two `find` commands, one for listing the files, the other for zipping the text files. Or execute a short script that zips files if their extension is txt.

Comment: Also, use `gzip`, `bzip2`, `lz4`, `xz` or similar if you're just compressing individual text files.   `zip` combines both archiving and compression (and an archive with only one file is kind of pointless unless you need to use it on a windows machine or something that doesn't have gzip).  gzip/xz/lz4/etc just do compression without archiving.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `-size +100M` where that `M` suffix is a non-standard extension selects files whose size is strictly greater than 100MiB, 104,857,600 bytes, not 100MB (100,000,000 bytes). For sizes (strictly) greater than 100MB, you'd need `-size +100000000c` (which is standard).

`-mtime +20` is for files that are 21 days¹ old exactly (or were, to the nanosecond at the time `find` was invoked) or older. You need `-mtime +19` for files older than 20 days (at least in POSIX compliant `find` implementations, not all are in that regard).

Assuming you're in a Bourne-like shell other than `zsh`, leaving that `$HOME` unquoted makes no sense as it makes no sense to invoke split+glob here. In POSIX shells, you can also use `~` in place of `"$HOME"`.

`zip` is a not very Unixy command. By default it expands wildcards by itself, so if you have a file called `*.txt`, `zip -m '*.txt.zip' '*.txt'` would actually create a zip file with all the `txt` files in the directory. It can get worse if that file is in a directory called `*` for instance. You can avoid that with the `-nw` flag, or use a more unixy command that supports that old zip format such as `bsdtar`.

If you do `find ~`, all the paths passed to `zip` will be absolute paths, so in the end, you'll have zip files whose members are listed with their full paths (`home/you/dir/file.txt`...). You can use the BSD/GNU `-execdir` `find` predicate or the `-j` option of `zip` to avoid that.

Note that not all `find` implementations will expand the `{}` in `{}.zip`, that is, when `{}` is not on its own in an argument to `-exec`. In those that don't, you'd need to resort to calling `sh` with `-exec sh -c 'zip -nw -m "$1.zip" -- "$1"' sh {} ';'`.

To match on the name of a file, you use the `-name` predicate. You can use `'(' -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.TXT' ')'` to match on either `txt` or `TXT` files, or `-name '*.[tT][xX][tT]'` or in some `find` implementations `-iname '*.txt'` to also include `Txt`, `tXT`... files. With several `find` implementations, `-name` requires the name of the file to be valid text in the user's locale. Since all of the `.txtTXT` characters are part of the portable character set, you can fix the locale to C to guarantee it will always match on files that end with those even if the rest of the file path is not valid text in the user's locale.

So:

```
LC_ALL=C find ~ '(' -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.TXT' ')' \
                -type f \
                -size +100000000c \
                -mtime +19 \
                -execdir zip -nw -m '{}.zip' -- '{}' ';'
```

Or use `zsh` and:

```
for f (~/**/*.(txt|TXT)(ND.L+100000000m+19)) zip -j -nw -m $f.zip $f
```

Note that zip is an old format from the late 80s with poor compression ratio by today's standards. Its only merit is that it's the only compression (actually, it does both archiving and compression while you only need the latter here) format supported out of the box on Microsoft operating systems.

Here, if you don't need interoperability with Microsoft OSes, you could use more modern compressors such as `xz`, `bzip2`. Even `gzip`  from the early 90s and which uses the same compression algorithm as `zip` would also give you better size reduction as it only takes care of the compressing. All those are also able to compress more than one file at a time, so would make the process of compressing many files more efficient as you could invoke the compressor fewer times.

For instance, you could do:

```
xz ~/**/*.(txt|TXT)(ND.L+100000000m+19)
```

From the `zsh` shell to better compress all those files in one invocation of `xz`.

---

<sup>¹ *days* here being 86400 (24 × 60 × 60) Unix seconds, not calendar days in that clock changes due to daylight saving are not taken into account.</sup>